# ModalView crashes in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm having an app crash in iOS7, but is working on iOS6. While debugging the next code from my AppDelegate, I checked that in iOS7 the next function is executed and then the modal view controller is loaded.

```
- (void)presentModalWebViewWithURL:(NSURL *)url title:(NSString *)title
{
    [self.modalWebViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.modalWebViewController = [[[MyModalWebViewController alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
    self.modalWebViewController.title = title;
    UINavigationController *nav = [self.modalWebViewController modalNavigationControllerWithTarget:self dismissSelector:@selector(dismissModalWebView)];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

In iOS6, I checked that the function stops the execution in the last line until the modal view controller is loaded.

What happens in iOS7 is that when the modal view controller tries to load running `viewWillAppear`, I was able to check that the modal view controller has changed all the values and even the properties are pointing to objects of different types. I guess that they are being deallocated but I can't figure out why and how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When you dismiss a modal view controller, you're supposed to call the dismiss method on the view controller that presented the view controller. Also the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` method is deprecated, you should instead use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`. So looking at your code, you should probably be calling the dismiss method on `self.window.rootViewController`, since that's what you're presenting modal views from.

Also, not knowing how the rest of your code looks, I'm assuming the first time this gets called, `self.modalWebViewController` is nil, so you probably want to check if `self.modalWebViewController` is set to something before you call dismiss, and also to set it to nil any time you do dismiss it.

Comment: Thanks Galvin. I get your advice and I will dig into that.